# How can I customize the conrfirmation dialog in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I customize the default confirmation box in angularjs. I have this code below and it displays the default without design. I want to change the buttons `ok and cancel` to `yes and no` but it doesn't work. 
my code is located at my js and it will display when the page is refreshed. Please help.

`var answer = confirm("are you sure u want to leave? ");`

Comment: Look into angular modals, but you need an additional library

Answer (score 0):

u can create u r own angular directive and hide show that directive based on u r requirement,or look into an https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert